# Exporting or copying mappings to a new CI server

Tags: teamcity, youtrack

We originally had one teamcity server instance with one youtrack instance. The project that we work on is a plugin based project and so over time we have had quite a significant number of mappings between CI builds and youtrack using the mapping feature.

The issue is now that we have moved that specific project with its hundred odd plugins to a new teamcity build server and now face the prospect of having to manually re-add the mappings which already exist as all other projects are still being managed via the existing build server

The question is that is there a pain free way to duplicate the already existing mappings or have youtrack automatically add all mappings from a particular project. I cant find a call for this in the rest api so looking for anything that will allow me not spend the next week adding mappings

Teamcity version is 10 and Youtrack version is 7

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the request that's sent to the server when you create a mapping. The API used to make this call is not public and is not documented, so it's a subject to change, but since you plan to do a one-time job using it, it can be way to go for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Hi Alex , can you kindly help with more information as to how to do this? We cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: I meant that you can view the request in browser console and then issue a similar one using curl or any other REST client. Pay attention to Authorization header.